# Can unlink used in web app to delete image?

Tags: php

I am new Jr Dev. I want to delete my Picture after I capture it on my phone and attach it on PHP. can anyone have an idea? I run it online. and nothing happens.

```php
$fileNameNew = 'Capture_Image0099123123.PNG';
$Capture = '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Capture Image/' . $fileNameNew;
   
if(unlink($Capture)){
         echo 'The file '.$fileNameNew.' has been deleted';
      }else{
          echo 'The file '.$fileNameNew.' doesnot exist';
      }
  

# How to Delete an Image in your phone using php unlink?
```

Comment: Do you have a way to actually run PHP on your phone? And with the needed permissions? If so, how?

Comment: To word M.Eriksson's question differently: where are you expecting to put this code? How are you going to run it? Apart from a missing semicolon on the first line, and an unlikely file name (extensions are usually all uppercase or all lowercase, not mixed), it's reasonable code; but it's not clear what you're actually asking about it.

Comment: Sir @M.Eriksson I ran it thru web hosting, so I took a picture from my phone and then save it on my database by attaching a file. and I want that picture to be deleted from any phone or tablet gallery. So is it possible to delete an image on any phone or tablet?

Comment: Think of it this way: your web server is one computer, your phone is another computer, my phone is a third computer. I can't run something on my phone that deletes something on your phone; nor can you run something on your server that deletes something on my phone. To do that, you need to be running something *on my phone*, which I have granted some kind of security access to. That will be more complex than a few lines of PHP.